# Query for joins in Spring JPA

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have the below entities

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Aggregate {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long  id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "aggregate")
    private Set<Single> singleSet;
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Single {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private String id;

    private Integer number;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "agg_id")
    private Aggregate aggregate;
}
```

I also have the below repository

```java
public interface AggregateRepo extends CrudRepository<Aggregate, Long> {

}
```

I want to return all associated `Single` records where `number` in object `Single` is equal to some random number

I am assuming that the query will be something like this

```java
public interface AggregateRepo extends CrudRepository<Aggregate, Long> {
    public List<Single> findBySingleSet_Number(Integer number);
}
```

However when I try to use Intellij to complete my named query it always populates like this

```java
public interface AggregateRepo extends CrudRepository<Aggregate, Long> {
    public List<Single> findBySingleSet_Empty_Number(Integer number);
}
```

I am wondering what the `Empty` stands for ?

Also should I create another `Single` repository since the query is related to returning `Single` records.